# Coinbase Pro Historical rates, how to get with websocket?

Tags: coinbase-api

The coinbase pro docs states: "Historical rates should not be polled frequently. If you need real-time information, use the trade and book endpoints along with the websocket feed."

What does it mean by use the "trade" and "book" endpoints along with websocket feed? Anyone have an example?

Comment: Found a reference to these things in [the documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#websocket-feed), however it doesn't talk about those
 endpoints anywhere I can find. I'm also not very experienced with this stuff, so perhaps the info is there and I just don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#market-data - for getting the current orderbook orders.

See https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-trades for the `/trades` endpoint

Right beneath Trades is https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-historic-rates (the one you shouldn't poll frequently).

https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#get-product-order-book - orderbook documentation

HTH

Comment: In your response, there is no channel or websocket type to subscribe. To which channel can we subscribe to have the historical rates ?

Comment: You don't subscribe to historic rates using the websockets. The endpoint is: `GET /products/<product-id>/candles`. You just need to request this data if you want it. Users are advised not to hit this endpoint frequently since it consumes a decent chunk of bandwidth. There are more efficient means for maintaining live price updates.